# Send the token from one domain to other domain with JavaScript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, single-sign-on

I want to achieve single sign on functionality.
After research I came accross, that I can pass the token from the masterdomain to other cross origin domains via message through the iframe.

However I can't reproduce this functionality. I don't get the actual message displayed, just JSON objects, like
[image]

I am trying that in two separate angular applications, running on different ports in localhost.

In my application, which is "masterdomain" and is running on: http://localhost:4200, where I have login system, the code is following:

```
  let token = this.getJwtToken();

  // Send the message with the token to the other domain
  var targetDomain = 'http://localhost:38447'; // Replace with the correct domain

  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = targetDomain; // Create a separate HTML file to receive the token
  iframe.style.display = 'none';

  iframe.onload = function () {
    iframe.contentWindow?.postMessage(token, 'token');
  };
```

And then the other separate domain, which is http://localhost:38447, in which I want to access the token retrieved from localstorage, to sucessfully single sign on, I have following code

```
   window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
      var message = e.data;
      console.log(message);
    });
```

I also followed this article, and I get same responses in the console
https://avinashsdalvi.medium.com/cross-domain-sharing-resources-like-login-cookies-f12ca54eae44

Thanks to everyone for help!